# Newby question - add a column to a report with custom data

Tags: custom-reports

I apologize in advance if my request looks like a mess :)
I'm used to working with excel, and am new to SalesForce.

I have a report with the names of departments, and I need to group by those department names. However, However, the department names are not clear enough for my needs.

I'm looking to do the following:
add a column that uses a custom formula, and this is how I would do it in excel:

```
=IF(A2="Biotech","BIO",IF(A2="Genetics","GEN",A2))
```

How would I go about adding something like this to a SalesForce report?

Also, instead of using an exact match, how can I do the following:

```
IF (FIELD_Name) CONTAINS "biot" THEN "BIO" ESLE IF()....
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom formula field in an object that contains department name, then add it as a column to a report.
Formula fields have almost the same syntax:

```
IF(logical_test, value_if_true, value_if_false).
```

So, in your case it should be like this: `IF(departmentName  = "Biotech", "BIO",  IF(departmentName = "Genetics", "GEN", departmentName))`
where departmentName is an API name of the field, like departmentName__c.

CONTAINS(text, compare_text) function also may help you.